Retrying an Async Stream Request when Rate Limits are reached
I am running a stream of requests in two stages. One stage gets some information from one endpoint, then sends those responses to stage two to make further API requests. In a real-world scenario there are two rate limits imposed:
Local: 20 requests per second
Global: 100 requests per 2 minutes
I have created a Arc<TokenBucket> type with a semaphore that allows me to honor these limits most of the time, however due to the intricacies of clock synchronization, sometimes the rate limit can be exceeded by accident. The API does provide in it's response headers an integer in seconds that tells you how long to back off.
This is all great, but via either part of my two-step stream I am trying to understand how when I receive a reqwest::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS (or status code 429), I can sleep the remainder of time (as provided by the API's response headers) and then retry where I left off when the request failed. Given that things are running concurrently I want to be able to retry any requests that might have failed, or somehow block the rest of my requests as soon as one of them receive a 429.
Some reproducible code simulating what I am trying to accomplish with httpbin.org:
use core::pin::pin;
use futures::stream::{self as stream, StreamExt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Instant;
use tokio::sync::Semaphore;
use tokio::time::{interval, Duration};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Sample {
    #[serde(rename = "Content-Length")]
    pub content_length: String,
    #[serde(rename = "retry-after")]
    pub retry_after: String,
}

/*
    Impl taken from
    https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Semaphore.html
*/
struct TokenBucket {
    sem: Arc<Semaphore>,
    jh: tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl TokenBucket {
    fn new(duration: Duration, capacity: usize) -> Self {
        let sem = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(capacity));

        // refills the tokens at the end of each interval
        let jh = tokio::spawn({
            let sem = sem.clone();
            let mut interval = interval(duration);
            interval.set_missed_tick_behavior(tokio::time::MissedTickBehavior::Skip);

            // continuously add more semaphore capacity on every tick
            async move {
                loop {
                    interval.tick().await;
                    //println!("tick at {:.2?}", Instant::now());

                    // only add a permit if we are below capacity
                    if sem.available_permits() < capacity {
                        sem.add_permits(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Self { jh, sem }
    }

    async fn acquire(&self) {
        // This can return an error if the semaphore is closed, but we
        // never close it, so this error can never happen.
        let permit = self.sem.acquire().await.unwrap();
        // To avoid releasing the permit back to the semaphore, we use
        // the `SemaphorePermit::forget` method.
        permit.forget();
    }
}

impl Drop for TokenBucket {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // kill the background task so it stops taking up resources when we
        // don't need it anymore.
        self.jh.abort();
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // program start
    let now = Instant::now();

    // there are two rate limits I must obey so I will make two buckets that will leak capacity
    // at a global and local interval
    let local_cap = 20;
    let local_interval = Duration::from_secs_f32(1.0 / local_cap as f32);
    let local_bucket = Arc::new(TokenBucket::new(local_interval, local_cap));

    let global_cap = 100;
    let global_interval = Duration::from_secs_f32(120.0 / global_cap as f32);
    let global_bucket = Arc::new(TokenBucket::new(global_interval, global_cap));

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut s = pin!(stream::iter((1..).step_by(1))
        .filter_map(|i| {
            let client = client.clone();
            let global_bucket = global_bucket.clone();
            let local_bucket = local_bucket.clone();
            async move {
                // api request which will provide resp headers with retry-after
                let url = format!("https://httpbin.org/response-headers?retry-after={i}");

                // take up capacity to make a request
                global_bucket.acquire().await;
                local_bucket.acquire().await;

                // check status of the response to determine next steps
                let resp = (client.get(url).send().await).ok()?;
                match resp.status() {
                    // response is good, deserialize it properly
                    reqwest::StatusCode::OK => {
                        let data = (resp.json::<Sample>().await).ok()?;
                        return Some(data);
                    }
                    reqwest::StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS => {
                        // get headers and sleep the remaining seconds
                        let retry_after =
                            resp.headers().get("retry-after").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
                        // how to retry here ?
                        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(
                            retry_after.parse::<u64>().unwrap(),
                        ))
                        .await;
                        None

                    }
                    // for brevity, but I'd potentially do retries
                    // based on other problem statuses
                    _ => None,
                }
            }
        })
        .take_while(|r| { futures::future::ready(r.content_length.parse::<u64>().unwrap() > 90) })
        // make more requests based off of information with d
        .flat_map_unordered(20, |d| {
            println!("{:?}", d);
            let client = client.clone();
            let global_bucket = global_bucket.clone();
            let local_bucket = local_bucket.clone();
            Box::pin(futures::stream::once(async move {
                let url = format!("https://httpbin.org/get");
                global_bucket.acquire().await;
                local_bucket.acquire().await;
                
                // need to potentially handle retries here too...
                let data = client
                    .get(url)
                    .send()
                    .await
                    .unwrap()
                    .json::<serde_json::Value>()
                    .await;
                data
            }))
        }));

    // consume the stream data
    let mut i = 0;
    while let Some(d) = s.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", d);
        i += 1
    }
    println!("processed {} requests", i);
    println!("INFO: program time elapsed: {:.2?}", now.elapsed());
}

EDIT:
Amended code:
use core::pin::pin;
use futures::stream::{self as stream, StreamExt};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::time::Instant;
use tokio::time::{interval, Duration};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Sample {
    #[serde(rename = "Content-Length")]
    pub content_length: String,
    #[serde(rename = "retry-after")]
    pub retry_after: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // program start
    let now = Instant::now();

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut s = pin!(stream::iter((1..).step_by(1))
        .filter_map(|i| {
            let client = client.clone();
            async move {
                // api request which will provide resp headers with retry-after
                let url = format!("https://httpbin.org/response-headers?retry-after={i}");

                // continuously check status of the response
                // to determine next steps
                loop {
                    let resp = (client.get(&url).send().await).ok()?;
                    match resp.status() {
                        reqwest::StatusCode::OK => {
                        // response is good, deserialize it properly
                            return Some((resp.json::<Sample>().await).ok()?);
                        }
                        // we need to back off according to the headers retry-after value
                        reqwest::StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS => {
                            // get headers and sleep the remaining seconds
                            let retry_after =
                                resp.headers().get("retry-after").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

                            println!("sleeping for {retry_after}s...");

                            // sleep for the the prescribed seconds
                            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(
                                retry_after.parse::<u64>().unwrap(),
                            ))
                            .await;
                            continue;
                        }
                        _ => {
                            println!("resp status {:?}", resp.status());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .take_while(|r| { futures::future::ready(r.content_length.parse::<u64>().unwrap() < 92) })
        // make more requests based off of information with d
        .flat_map_unordered(20, |_d| {
            let client = client.clone();
            Box::pin(futures::stream::once(async move {
                let url = format!("https://httpbin.org/get");
                // continuously check status of the response
                // to determine next steps
                loop {
                    let resp = client.get(&url).send().await.unwrap();
                    match resp.status() {
                        // response is good, deserialize it properly
                        reqwest::StatusCode::OK => {
                            return resp.json::<serde_json::Value>().await;
                        }
                        // we need to back off according to the headers retry-after value
                        reqwest::StatusCode::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS => {
                            // get headers and sleep the remaining seconds
                            let retry_after =
                                resp.headers().get("retry-after").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
                            println!("sleeping for {retry_after}s...");

                            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(
                                retry_after.parse::<u64>().unwrap(),
                            ))
                            .await;
                            continue;
                        }
                        // other error... to be handled
                        _ => continue,
                    }
                }
            }))
        }));

    // consume the stream items
    let mut i = 0;
    while let Some(d) = s.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", d);
        i += 1
    }
    println!("processed {} requests", i);
    println!("INFO: program time elapsed: {:.2?}", now.elapsed());
}



There are potentially several different questions contained here. With regards to rate limiting, is your goal to avoid hammering the API? Since if your API tells you the backoff time, you don't need to really implement any rate limiting algo, just wait for a duration equal to the header value. If you really do need rate limiting, I wouldn't suggest this semaphore base strategy - track the number of requests made in the last second and wait for a time if that number exceeds 20 (likewise for the 2nd limit).

@user2407038 I see what you are saying., however the issue is that I don't know how much longer to sleep until I make a failed request (429). The API doesn't return that header if its a successful 200 response or else. So I believe I still need a retry strategy after I hit a 429 and then learn how much longer I need to wait.

@user2407038 any reason on not using the Semaphore strategy? I do have successful runs without any 429s sometimes, but its not consistent as sometimes things get out of sync and that pipeline essentially fails to get all necessary data because it would skip the bad request.

I am suggesting you ONLY sleep when you get the 429. This depends on whether you care about hitting the API rate limit (429 response or not). For example if you issue 40 requests in 0.01s, then 20 will return 200 and the other 200 return 429 with a backoff time in the header. The failed 20 requests can just wait for that backoff time and retry (in a loop in case they hit more 429s). ....

...  If you DO care about avoiding the 429 in the first place, then you need to combine the two strategies (waiting based on retry-after and waiting based on local rate limits). Your current semaphore implementation doesn't really allow you to do this (at least not easily) because it only provides you with the "acquire" operation, which might block until the rate limit is free, but doesn't tell you WHEN it will become free. What you should do is before making every request, get the 'backoff time' for each strategy (you have 3), and wait for the maximum amount of time indicated by all of them

@user2407038 so basically like a while resp.status() == reqwest::TOO_MANY_REQUESTS sleep if header says so and remake the request? I'll give it a try and see how the API responds.

@user2407038 I added some amended code to the question if you want to take a look. Its pretty large to be doing in closures, so I'd likely take the core handling of each request into their own fn() in the real-world example as I might handle each stage of requests responses slightly differently. Or maybe I could make a generic handler that can handle the responses within each stage of the stream  and sleep/react accordingly since each endpoint of this API do share the global rate limit policy. Again, thanks for all your thoughts and suggestions. I've learned so much!
